# Parsing JSON Ansible returns undefined value

Tags: json, ansible

This is the JSONcontent I registered:

```
results:[{
    "json": {
        "item": {
            "param": [
            [
               {
                "metrics1": "A",
                "metrics2": "B"
                "metrics3": "C"
              },
               {
                "metrics1": "D",
                "metrics2": "E"
                "metrics3": "F"
              },
               {
                "metrics1": "G",
                "metrics2": "H"
                "metrics3": "I"
              }
            ],
            [
               {
                "metrics1": "J",
                "metrics2": "K"
                "metrics3": "L"
              },
               {
                "metrics1": "M",
                "metrics2": "N"
                "metrics3": "O"
              },
               {
                "metrics1": "P",
                "metrics2": "Q"
                "metrics3": "R"
              }
            ],
           ],
         }
    }
}
]
```

I want to get metrics2 and metrics3 as a table where metrics2 value as column1 and metrics3 value as column2

I try parsing metrics2 first but it returns undefined value like this

```
"parseJSON_list": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]"
```

What I tried is:

```
parseJSON: "{{ JSONcontent['results'] | map(attribute='json') | map(attribute='item') | map(attribute='param') | map(attribute= 'metrics2') | list }}"
```

It works fine until `map(attribute= 'metrics2')`

What should I do?

Comment: [edit] the question and fix the YAML syntax of *results*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Table where metrics2 value as column1 and metrics3 value as column2."***

A: For example,

```yaml
tab_m2_m3: "{{ param|json_query('[][].[metrics2, metrics3]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  tab_m2_m3:
    - [B, C]
    - [E, F]
    - [H, I]
    - [K, L]
    - [N, O]
    - [Q, R]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    param:
      - - {metrics1: A, metrics2: B, metrics3: C}
        - {metrics1: D, metrics2: E, metrics3: F}
        - {metrics1: G, metrics2: H, metrics3: I}
      - - {metrics1: J, metrics2: K, metrics3: L}
        - {metrics1: M, metrics2: N, metrics3: O}
        - {metrics1: P, metrics2: Q, metrics3: R}
    tab_m2_m3: "{{ param|json_query('[][].[metrics2, metrics3]') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: tab_m2_m3
```

Comment: I tried your solution in 2 ways:

1. parseJSON: "{{ JSONcontent['results'] | map(attribute='json') | map(attribute='item') | map(attribute='param') | map(attribute= 'metrics2') |  json_query('[][].[metrics2, metrics3]') | list }}"

and the output shows: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

2. i tried to set fact the output of parseJSON like this:
parseJSON2: "{{ parseJSON |  json_query('[][].[metrics2, metrics3]') }}

and the output shows: 
"parseJSON2": ""

Are my implementations wrong?

Comment: i tried making a test case like yours and it also returns null value

Comment: turns out it was because i use set fact instead of vars, when i use vars it works completely fine, thanks!